# Can I run Wallpaper Engine (from Steam) in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: compatibility

I am about to switch to Ubuntu and I wanted to know if there is a way to run Wallpaper Engine in Ubuntu since in Wallpaper Engine's store page, minimum OS requirements only specify Windows.

Comment: https://github.com/Almamu/linux-wallpaperengine
use this github tutorial, it may be help you

Answer (score 0):

You can't run software designed to manipulate the **Windows** desktop with Ubuntu.

If that is an exlusive feature you need then you should not switch to Ubuntu.

However there are a lot of customizations of the GNOME desktop (Ubnutu default) available (see e.g. [GNOME-Look](https://www.gnome-look.org/)), and of course there are many [Ubuntu flavors](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours) that come with a variety of other desktop managers, each with a different look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

Settings - > Steam Play -> Check 'Enable Steam Play for all other Title', then select the last version of proton. Press 'Ok' button, restart your steam and there you go, you are now enabled to install wallpaper engine.

(I don't know if this feature has on every single linux version. but on ubuntu it works well.)

Comment: I allways check protondb.com for steam stuff. The entry for ["Wallpaper Engine"](https://www.protondb.com/app/431960) is marked as "Borked". It will only work if you use KDE as your desktop environment (ie. might work on Kubuntu).